# Delete Child Controls from designer code

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, designer, tabpage

I am creating my own TabControl with custom TabPages. It is coming along well except for the deletion part. When I add the TabControl to a Form in the Designer everything works well, 2 default TabPages are added and the control is drawn. But when I delete the TabControl from the Form in the Designer, the TabPages that are part of the TabControl.Controls Collection are not deleted from the Designer Code. They just lose their Parent.

Any thoughts?

For the creation I use the following code.

```
    public class CustomTabControlDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{
    DesignerVerbCollection _fVerbs;
    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fVerbs == null)
            {
                _fVerbs = new DesignerVerbCollection(new[] { new DesignerVerb("Add Tab", OnAdd), new DesignerVerb("Del Tab", OnDel) });
            }

            return _fVerbs;
        }
    }

    void OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDesignerHost designerHost = (IDesignerHost)GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        if (designerHost != null)
        {
            WTabPage newPage = (WTabPage)designerHost.CreateComponent(typeof(WTabPage));
            //newPage.Text = newPage.Name;

            ((WTab)Component).Controls.Add(newPage);
        }
    }
    void OnDel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDesignerHost designerHost = (IDesignerHost)GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        if (designerHost != null)
        {
            ((WTab)Component).Controls.Remove(((WTab)Component).SelectedTab);
        }
    }

    public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            OnAdd(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    //protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    //{
    //    for (int i = ((WTab)Component).Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    //    {
    //        ((WTab)Component).Controls.Remove(((WTab)Component).Controls[i]);
    //    }

    //    base.Dispose(disposing);
    //}

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        // Selection of tabs via mouse
        if (m.Msg == 0x201/*WM_LBUTTONDOWN*/)
        {
            WTab control = (WTab)Component;

            int lParam = m.LParam.ToInt32();

            Point hitPoint = new Point(lParam & 0xffff, lParam >> 0x10);

            if (Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd) == null) // Navigation
            {
                if (hitPoint.X < 18 && control.SelectedIndex > 0) // Left
                {
                    control.SelectedIndex--;
                }

                else
                {
                    control.SelectedIndex++; // Right}
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Header click
                for (int i = 0; i < control.TabCount; i++)
                {
                    if (control.GetTabRect(i).Contains(hitPoint))
                    {
                        control.SelectedIndex = i;

                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs de)
    {
        ((IDropTarget)((WTab)Component).SelectedTab).OnDragDrop(de);
    }
    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs de)
    {
        ((IDropTarget)((WTab)Component).SelectedTab).OnDragEnter(de);
    }
    protected override void OnDragLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        ((IDropTarget)((WTab)Component).SelectedTab).OnDragLeave(e);
    }
    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs de)
    {
        ((IDropTarget)((WTab)Component).SelectedTab).OnDragOver(de);
    }
}
```

The OnAdd and OnDel are triggerd by the Tasks not when the control is added or removed: [Task Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ4Y7.png)

Comment: Could it be, that you should replace `((WTab)Component).Controls.Remove(((WTab)Component).SelectedTab);` in `OnDel` with `((WTab)Component).Controls.Clear();`?

Comment: The OnDel method is not triggered when the control is deleted by my understanding, it is used in the TabControl Tasks when you press the triangle in the right top.

Comment: Do you override Dispose method of `WTab`? Can you post code of your controls `WTab` and  `WTabPage`? Especially code where pages are added/removed and any disposing methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Pablo notPicasso his answer I used the following code that seems to work. Any wrongs in this?

```
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        IDesignerHost designerHost = (IDesignerHost)GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        if (designerHost != null)
        {
            for (int i = ((WTab)Component).Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                //
                var tab = ((WTab)Component).Controls[i];

                //
                ((WTab)Component).Controls.Remove(tab);

                //
                designerHost.DestroyComponent(tab);
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `IDesignerHost.DestroyComponent(...)`?

```
void OnDel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IDesignerHost designerHost = (IDesignerHost) GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
    if (designerHost != null)
    {
        var tab = ((WTab) Component).SelectedTab;
        ((WTab) Component).Controls.Remove(tab);
        designerHost.DestroyComponent(tab);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OnDel is not triggered when the TabControl is deleted from the Form, it is used for the Control Tasks. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ4Y7.png